# Многомерный массив в одномерный с заменой ключей и значений

Tags: php, массивы

[image]

Существует массив выше. Его необходимо преобразовать в одномерный массив, где ключом будет является "id", а значением 'name'

То есть: 
**[6 => 'notebook-create', 8 => 'notebook-delete']**

И так далее)

Каким образом это реализовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $v) {
     $new_array[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
}
```